# Ping Monitor With Geographical Map

Tags: network-monitor, mapping

I’m looking for a ping monitor that allows me to enter in the addresses that the IPs are located and have it map out all monitored IPs on a geographical map. I’ve searched for a bit and the only thing I’ve found is Peplink-brand router specific hosted software that does this, but I’m looking for something that is more generic that works with any monitored IP. Price isn’t a concern at the moment but of course cheaper is better.